# Error in using Linked List in C program

Tags: c, error-handling, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I am working on an extra credit project for class and here are the specs:

- You will write a c program (you should use a design tool but I do not want to see it)
- The program will use dynamic memory to create a linked list (NO ARRAYS PERMITTED)
- The program will store unlimited number of student records (limited only by RAM).
- A student record will consist of Student Name, and Age…you may need to add two additional fields to make this work.
- The program will have a way for the user to added records.
- The program will have a way for the user to display ALL records (to the screen only, no sort needed).
- The program needs a way to quit.

I have all the code finished, but I am getting this pesky error. This is exactly what I see on my computer:

```
1>linkedProject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _add referenced in    function _main
1>E:\Spring 2013\C Programing Class\linkedProject\Debug\linkedProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

And here is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define pause system ("pause")

// prototype variables
struct node * initnode(char*, int);
void printnode(struct node*);
void printflist(struct node*);
void add(struct node*);
struct node* searchname(struct node*, char*);

struct node{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = (struct node*) NULL;
struct node *end = (struct node*) NULL;

struct node* initnode(char *name, int age){
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = (struct node*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    if(ptr == NULL) 
        return (struct node*) NULL;
    else {
        strcpy(ptr->name, name);
        ptr->age = age;
        return ptr;
     }
}

void printnode(struct node *ptr) {
    printf("Name -> %s\n", ptr->name);
    printf("Age -> %d\n", ptr->age);
}

void printlist (struct node *ptr) {
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printnode(ptr);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}



main() {
    char name[20];
    int age, choice = 1;
    struct node *ptr;
    while(choice != 3){
        system("cls");
        printf("1. Add a name\n");
        printf("2. List all names\n");
        printf("3. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Menu Selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice) {
        case 1: printf("\nEnter a name: ");
            scanf("%s", &name);
            printf("Enter age: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
            ptr = initnode(name, age);
            add (ptr);
            break;
        case 2: printlist(head);
            break;
        case 3: exit(3);
        default: printf("Invalid Entry");
        }// end of switch


    }// end of while

}// end of main
```

All help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The answer is what is `add (ptr);`?

Answer (score 1):

The linker is telling you that it can't find the `add` function.

You have declared:

> void add(struct node*)

in your prototypes, but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `add` method in `prototype`. and `add(ptr) call` in main method. But I cann't see `add method definiton`. That's why, Compiler rise linker error.